# using 'While' statements

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.8

When trying to make it so that when the user does not type log in or register in the input, the program will ask for them to please choose from the choices they have, but when i try to at the or operator into the condition of the while statement and click run, the program will keep on looping saying the same thing even though the user types in Login or Register, but when i remove the or operator, the while statement works....... ps i am a beginner at python

def menu():

```
print("Welcome to the banking app")
print("Would you like to login or register?")

ans = input()

while ans != "login" or 'register':
    print("Please choose the choices given")
    ans = input()



if ans == 'login':
    print('They want to log in')
elif ans == 'register':
    print('They want to register')
```

menu()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your condition, `or` is not appropriate in this case, you need to use `and` instead. But if you need to add more elements to the condition, it can be really huge, so you can also verify if `ans` is inside a list of predefined answers:

```
print("Welcome to the banking app")
print("Would you like to login or register?")

ans = ""

while ans not in ["register", "login"]::
    ans = input("Please choose the choices given ")

print('They want to ', ans)
```

Answer (score 3):

The line `while ans != "login" or 'register':` does not do what you think it does. It first evaluates `ans != "login"` as True or False. It then evaluates `'register'` as True or False. You see, 'register' will always evaluate a true because it is non-empty (python evaluates all non-empty items to be True in a boolean context).

What you want to use is:

```
while ans != "login" and ans != "register":
```

You could also use:

```
while ans not in ["login", "register"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to the banking app")
print("Would you like to login or register?")
ans=''
while ans != "login" or "register":
    print("Please choose the choices given")
    ans = input()
    if ans == 'login':
        print('They want to log in')
        break
    elif ans == 'register':
        print('They want to register')
        break
```